# Las páginas con el código fuente de una revisión usan el favicon de Stack Overflow en inglés

Tags: bug, diseño

Dada una página de revisiones ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/74007/revisions)) vemos que el favicon es el de Stack Overflow en español. Esto es, el que tiene color amarillo de fondo.

Sin embargo, si se selecciona la opción *código fuente* ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/ba22a2f8-cbcb-4c93-8611-b049bb65c3f1/view-source)), entonces el favicon es el de la página Stack Overflow en inglés.

Visualmente:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, las páginas equivalentes en Meta no tienen ningún favicon ([ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/97257934-3e65-4bb2-995c-ddb9a2aa0f0a/view-source)).

Comment: Vaya ojo tienes. Efectivamente, confirmo que en mi caso es asi también.

Comment: HHAH vaya, pues si que estás atento

Comment: Y de hecho no sé vosotros pero a mí en Meta no me sale ningún icono ([ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/97257934-3e65-4bb2-995c-ddb9a2aa0f0a/view-source)) @Pikoh

Comment: @fedorqui tambien me pasa!

Comment: @fedorqui confirmado, en meta no sale favicon

Comment: había otro caso... estoy tratando de recordar cuál era

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto no es un problema de Stack Overflow en español, es el comportamiento normal de Chrome. Hice una pregunta sobre esto (para otra página diferente) en el sitio en inglés. Busco el enlace y lo comparto.

Comment: Pues no encuentro la publicación... pero ahora te pongo una respuesta explicando ese comportamiento en Chrome (y creo que también era en otros navegadores).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro probablemente es porque esas páginas no tienen definido `<link rel="shortcut icon" ...>`, por lo que coge por defecto el de la página principal, esto es, el de stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @fedorqui correcto. Si no se define un favicon, el navegador intenta tomar favicon.ico (si no recuerdo mal) automáticamente del root del servidor (y ese es el de so en inglés). Estoy en el móvil y no lo puedo poner como respuesta ahora mismo, si quieres ponlo tú.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero quizás la respuesta a esta pregunta no es explicar el motivo, sino decir "*ya se agregó el favicon a esa página*" ;-)

Comment: Eso es. Como dice @mariano, yo entiendo que la cuestión aqui no es explicar el problema, sino ver si se puede solucionar :)

Comment: Comprendo. Pero igual el tema va más allá del alcance de nuestro meta. Si es un cambio que afecta a varios sitios de la red de SE, debería plantearse en Meta Stack Exchange.